# Android Studio: get emulator back after "Hide" (Shift + Esc)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

In Android Studio, if I accidentally press the "Hide" button in the Emulator window, it'll disappear but the Emulator will be still running so that I won't be able to start it again. What is the best way to return the emulator back?